# Can Springdoc OpenAPI read @PreAuthorize annotations to indicate users which permissions they need?

Tags: java, spring, springdoc

I have a project where I use SpringDoc OpenAPI library to auto generate my docs. I have some endpoints like so

```
@Operation(tags = "Something")
@RequestMapping( . . . )
@PreAuthorize("isSuperadmin() || hasRole('MegaRole')")
public void doSomething() {
    . . .
}
```

Is it possible for SpringDoc to automatically read the `@PreAuthorize` statement so it can show somehow what's within it? That way users would see which permissions do they need to call the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Same question as this one: [Automatic Swagger annotation-based description generation in Springdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876585/automatic-swagger-annotation-based-description-generation-in-springdoc)

I have experimented this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65884462), you must just change the algorithm to parse `preAuthorizeAnnotation.get().value()` to recognize `hasRole` embedded value or other specifics attributes.