# How to display required user roles in for OpenAPI UI?

Tags: java, spring, openapi

I have a Spring Boot 3 project and I want to show the required role/permission in the OpenApi UI for my endpoints. I have had this working before, in the past when I used Swagger instead OpenApi, however I am not sure what changes I need to make to get it to work for this.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.OperationBuilderPlugin;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.OperationContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.DescriptionResolver;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.common.SwaggerPluginSupport;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.OAS_PLUGIN_ORDER)// this used to be: SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER for Swagger
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyOperationBuilderPlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

  private final DescriptionResolver descriptionResolver;

  @Override
  public void apply(OperationContext context) {
    try {
      String apiRoleAccessNoteText = "Required role: None";
      Optional<PreAuthorize> preAuthorizeAnnotation = context.findAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
      if (preAuthorizeAnnotation.isPresent()) {
        apiRoleAccessNoteText =
            "Required role: "
                + preAuthorizeAnnotation
                    .get()
                    .value()
                    .replace("hasAuthority('", "")
                    .replace("')", "");
      }
      context.operationBuilder().notes(descriptionResolver.resolve(apiRoleAccessNoteText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error when creating swagger documentation for security roles: " + e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
    return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
  }
}
```

The UI looks like this

[image: No role showing]

However, it should show something like this (this is for a previous service using Swagger instead of OpenApi)
[image: Should look like this]

Comment: Here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524355/how-to-display-required-user-roles-access-control-information-in-swagger-ui-fo

Comment: @TacheDeChoco thats for using Swagger, not OpenApi

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom annotation `@UserRoleDescription` with a controller's method as below:

```
@GetMapping("/bytin/{tin}")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@Operation(summary = "Get company by Tax ID Number")
@UserRoleDescription
public CompanyDto getCompanyByTin(@PathVariable String tin) {
    ...
}
```

It results in a description containing an information about the required role:
[Swagger UI result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLrvt.png).

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserRoleDescription {

}
```

And description customizer:

```
@Component
public class UserRoleDescriptionCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        var annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(UserRoleDescription.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            var securedAnnotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Secured.class);
            if(securedAnnotation != null) {
                String description = operation.getDescription()==null ? "" : (operation.getDescription()+"\n");
                operation.setDescription(description + "Required role: **"+ String.join("or", securedAnnotation.value()) + "**");
            }
        }
        return operation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a workaround for that.
As roles in applications are strictly defined we can create a special annotation for each role that will be used for authorization and include *@PreAuthorize* annotation together with *@Operation* annotation.
*@Operation* enriches endpoint documentation by custom description.

So create annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('bar-admin')")
@Operation(description = "Required role: bar-admin")
public @interface AuthorizeBarAdmin {
}
```

Now you can use the *@AuthorizeBarAdmin* annotation instead
*@PreAuthorize("hasRole('bar-admin')")* and the custom description will be included.

Note: *@Operation* can be annotated on REST endpoint next to the *@Preauthorize* anyway, but always you need to remember about the additional annotation and copy the description many times. That's why the above solution is better.